# Getting the log contents + loopback.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to write log contents of `slc ctl log-dump 'middleware' --follow` to a text file `slc ctl log-dump 'middleware' --follow > log.txt` but its writing only the last few lines to the text file.

When i ran `slc ctl log-dump 'middleware' --follow` in console its printing all lines of the log content, but i can't see all those log contents in console so i wrote to file. Also according to doc `slc ctl log-dump 'middleware' --follow` will dump the `1MB` of log contents , i want that 1mb contents to write to file.

Also where is the location of log file?? I googled and it says `/var/log/upstart/strong-pm.log` but i couldn't found there

Also where `slc ctl log-dump 'middleware' --follow` this command fetching data from??

Plz share your ideas. Thanks in advance.